# useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-router, react-router-dom

See my code below. I'm trying to add this button that goes back to the previous page using `react-router-dom` but I get the below error, and also all the components on my website disappear.

Error:

> useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a component

My code:

```
function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>go back</button>
        <Nav/>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/upcoming/:user" element={<Upcoming/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/record/:user" element={<Record/>}/>
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

And this is the error I got in console:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 109, accepted):

This error throws in [useNavigate](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v6.2.2/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L512). [useInRouterContext](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v6.2.2/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L386) will check if the component(which uses `useNavigate` hook) is a descendant of a `<Router>`. If the component is **not** a descendant of the `<Router>` component, it will throw this [error](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/v6.2.2/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L516).

Here's the source code to explain why you can't use `useNavigate`, `useLocation` outside of the `Router` component:

> `useNavigate` uses `useLocation` underly, `useLocation` will get the [location](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dc37beb049e883e0e33c77a3897d4ca0891dd565/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L408) from [LocationContext](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dc37beb049e883e0e33c77a3897d4ca0891dd565/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L84) provider. If you want to get the react context, you should render the component as the descendant of a context provider.
> `Router` component use the [LocationContext.Provider](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dc37beb049e883e0e33c77a3897d4ca0891dd565/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L321) and [NavigationContext.Provider](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dc37beb049e883e0e33c77a3897d4ca0891dd565/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L320). That's why you need to render the component as the [children](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dc37beb049e883e0e33c77a3897d4ca0891dd565/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L322), so that `useNavigate` hook can get the context data from `NavigationContext` and `LocationContext` providers.

Your environment is browser, so you need to use `BrowserRouter`. `BrowserRouter` is built based on `Router`.

Refactor to this:

`App.jsx`:

```
function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>go back</button>
        <Nav/>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/upcoming/:user" element={<Upcoming/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/record/:user" element={<Record/>}/>
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
  );
}
```

`index.jsx`:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 27):

I had this same issue but with testing a component that has the hook `useNavigate` on it. Solved it by wrapping my component in a `Route` with `Routes` and `BrowserRouter`. Hope this helps others with the same error.

```
let container = null;
    beforeEach(() => {
    container = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
    // cleanup on exiting
    unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    container.remove();
    container = null;
});

test('finds qualified insurrance policies', () => {
    act(() => {
    render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>   
            <Route path="*" element= {<QuaifiedPolicies policyTypes={false} />}/>
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
        , container);
    });
    expect(screen.getByLabelText('some text'))
});
```

Comment: You don't need to make it a route just wrap it with BrowserRouter and the problem would be solved

Comment: Adding another level to this, if you have BrowserRouter but also are using Redux you need to have a Provider and store as well, otherwise you will get the 'can not find getState...' error. Just letting anyone else interested know: )

Answer (score 23):

For future reference: This error may also occur

- if you import your `<Router>` from `react-router-dom` and import `useNavigate` from `react-router`
- if you import `useNavigate` et al from a *different version* of the package than `BrowserRouter`, e.g. v5 and v6

Comment: For me it was `<BrowserRouter>` was imported from v5 and `useNavigate` from v6 (big project, slowly migrating over to v6 little by little). But this answer gave me the hint to check my import.

Comment: This is a tricky one, but this answer really helped me with above error. I was using "react-router-dom", but VSCode sneaky imported from "react-router-dom6"

Comment: This was my issue on react-router-dom version 6.10 vs 6.16. Thank you!

Comment: heavy thumbs up for this gem. difficult and sneaky problem.

Answer (score 16):

You are using hook outside `BrowserRouter` provider. That's why you are getting errors. Refactor your component like below to solve this issue:

```
function Root() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>go back</button>
      <Nav />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/upcoming/:user" element={<Upcoming />} />
        <Route exact path="/record/:user" element={<Record />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Root />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Problem

My exact error was

```
console.error
      Error: Uncaught [Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.]
```

and it happened only when running the following unit test code:

```
// Act
const button: HTMLElement = render(<MyButton myChoice="myChoice" />).container;

// Assert
expect(button).toHaveTextContent("myChoice");
```

### Solution

I solved the error by wrapping the rendered element with `<BrowserRouter>`:

```
// Act
const button: HTMLElement = render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <MPBenefitChoiceButton selectedChoice={selectedChoice} />
    </BrowserRouter>
).container;

// Assert
expect(button).toHaveTextContent(buttonText);
```

Answer (score 2):

The component where you use `useNavigate` should wrap by `<Router> ... </Router>`

e.g.

```
<Router>
      <AuthProvider>    <----- useNavigate used in this component 
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<LoginForm />} />
          <Route exact path="/register" element={<RegisterForm />} />
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
</Router>
<OtherComponent/>  <----- if useNavigate use inside this component then  
                         error occur because useNavaigate work inside  
                         <Router> Component so it should wrap inside <Router>
```

Like this :

```
<Router>
      <AuthProvider>    
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<LoginForm />} />
          <Route exact path="/register" element={<RegisterForm />} />
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
      <OtherComponent/>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the unit tests wrap your components with MemoryRouter and provide the initialEntries correctly with pathname and search params

```
import { MemoryRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { renderWithProviders, screen } from '../../../test/test-utils'

import { Case } from '../index'
import { Home } from '../../home/index'

describe('Case component', () => {
  const queryParams = 'caseRef=2023030026&token=testToken&refreshToken=testRefreshToken'

  it('renders "Loading..." when token, refreshToken, or caseRef are missing', () => {
    renderWithProviders(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[{ pathname: '/case?', search: queryParams }]}>
        <Case />
      </MemoryRouter>
    )
    expect(screen.getByText(/Loading.../)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

  it('renders Home once the application has loaded', () => {
    renderWithProviders(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/case', '/2023030026']}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/:caseRef" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </MemoryRouter>
    )
    expect(screen.getByText(/Overview/)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a mock tag and wrap the tag you want to test inside a

```
<BroserRouter></BroserRouter>
```

tag
like this:

```
const Mocktest =()=>{
  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

and then render the `Mocktest` component
like this:

```
  test('test app',()=>{
    render(<Mocktest/>);
    const yourTag= screen.findByLabelText(/choose time/i);
    expect(yourTag).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```