# React router v6 programmatically redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am in `/customerOrders/13` page and from there I try to redirect to `/customerOrders/14` using `navigate('/customerOrders/14')`. Even though the URL is updated, page is not redirected to `/customerOrders/14`.

Below are code fragments I extracted related to this from the codebase.

**App.js**

```js
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
...
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="customerOrders/:id" element={<CustomerOrderForm />}></Route>
    </Routes>
<Router>
```

**CustomerOrderForm.jsx**

```js
import { useNavigate  } from "react-router-dom";
...

const CustomerOrderForm = () => {
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const save = async () => {
        //
        // logic to persist data goes here...
        //

        navigate(`/customerOrders/${customerOrderId}`);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please add the code of the component that is rendered with route `customerOrder/14`. If you are using useEffect in that component, add the id param from route as a dependency to useEffect.

Comment: use `import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'; `const history = useNavigate();`  then `history('...');`

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal I tried this before and I got error: `useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`

Comment: @MohitKushwaha I imported `import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";` and then `let id = useParams().id;`. Id is fetched already... but the problem is I cannot redirect from this page to another.

Comment: @MohitKushwaha I updated the question with code as you requested. I removed `history` as well. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70491774/usenavigate-may-be-used-only-in-the-context-of-a-router-component) SO question and still no luck.

Comment: @LakmalPremaratne but why are you navigating to the same component, I cannot figure out what you are trying to implement. if you want to refresh the page if param (id) changes, then add it as dependency to useEffect.

Comment: @MohitKushwaha Thanks for getting back. I am on Customer Order (CO) 14 (`/customerOrders/14`) and from there the user can create a new CO through a modal dialog. When the modal dlg finishes, I want to navigate to newly created CO (say, 15) `/customerOrders/15`. That's the requirement I have to implement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you are on a given route:

```
<Route path="customerOrders/:id" element={<CustomerOrderForm />} />
```

and navigating to the same route already rendering the mounted component then the component needs to "listen" for changes to the route, in this case, specifically the `id` route match param that is updated. Use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `id` route match param to rerun any logic depending on it.

```
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

...

const CustomerOrderForm = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    // rerun logic depending on id value
  }, [id]);

  const save = async () => {
    //
    // logic to persist data goes here...
    //

    navigate(`/customerOrders/${customerOrderId}`);
  };

  ...

};
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is independent of whether you are redirecting inside a component or not:

```
// 1. history.ts
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
export const history = createBrowserHistory()

// 2. index.tsx
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { history } from './history.ts'

root.render(
  <HistoryRouter history={history}>
     </div>Hello React Router Redirect Feature</div>
  </HistoryRouter>
);

// 3. Your handle function
import { history } from './history.ts'

const getRedirected = (pathNext = '/') => {
  historyObject.push(pathNext);
  // or
  // historyObject.replace('/');
}
```

My environment:
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.11.0",
"history": "^5.3.0"

Now  you can use the history object in any non-react component function