# React.js useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-hooks, use-effect, react-context

Attempting to create a Context, and need to navigate triggered by reading local storage.

I can understand the error that it doesn't allow to use `useNavigate()` outside a `<Router>`, but what alternative can I use for this?

Code:

```
const ChatContext = createContext();

const ChatProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState()

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        const user = localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
        if (user) {
            setUser(JSON.parse(user))
        } else {
            navigate('/login')
        }

    }, [navigate])


    return <ChatContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>{children}</ChatContext.Provider>

}
```

Error:

```
> Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router>
> component.
> 
> The above error occurred in the <ChatProvider> component:
> 
> ChatProvider@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:733:11
> 
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
> handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to
> learn more about error boundaries.
```

Comment: Can you show me how are you using the ChatContext Provider? 

Looks like you are using it outside of the Router so it doesn't have access to the router context

Comment: `import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ChatProvider from './context/ChatProvider';

ReactDOM.render(
  <ChatProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ChakraProvider>
        <App />
      </ChakraProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>,
  </ChatProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);`

Comment: You currently have `<ChatProvider>` on the outside, and `<BrowserRouter>` inside of it. Swap the order so that the router is on the outside

Comment: Can you share your  `app.js`

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70491774/usenavigate-may-be-used-only-in-the-context-of-a-router-component