# Why redirect not working in next.js application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, next.js, react-router

I am new to next.js and i have an application built on top of it.
I run a timer of 10 seconds on the homepage and when the timer reaches 0 I want  otredirect user to a feedpack page in my pages folder.

Code for the same:

```
if(timer==0)
  {
    navigate('/feedback')
    clearTimeout(time);
  }
```

I am using `useNavigate hook` here and it gives me the following error:

```
useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

Comment: Next.js come with its [own built-in router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router). You shouldn't use `react-router-dom` in a Next.js app. See https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router.

Comment: The `useNavigate` hook can only be used within a `react-router-dom` routing context. If you want to use client-side routing you'll need to fully implement a client-side router.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70491774/usenavigate-may-be-used-only-in-the-context-of-a-router-component) you can read more about this error

What you need is to use [useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) hook.

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function ComponentName() {
  const router = useRouter();
  if(timer==0) {
    router.push('/feedback')
    clearTimeout(time);
  }
  return (...);
}
```

Comment: I did that and it works, but it gives me a 404 error saying page not found. Although I have created feedback.tsx file in the pages folder