# useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component is the error that I'm getting in the console

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-router-dom

I think it's because I'm using the latest version of react and they have changed many components, since. All I want to do is navigate to another page.
[image: This is the error]

I tried wrapping it it

```
<Routes>
              <button
                className="whatevr"
                onClick={() => {
                  navigate("../FeaturePage");
                }}
              >
                Features
              </button>
            </Routes>
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70491774/usenavigate-may-be-used-only-in-the-context-of-a-router-component answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Based on both errors regarding the use of the `useNavigate` and `useRoutes` hooks ***both*** needing to be used within a routing context, i.e. called with in a `<Router>` component, it seems that you are *not* actually doing this.

Render the app, or these specific components within a router.

Example:

```
const App = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" .... />
      ... other routes ...
    </Routes>
  </>
);
```

Parent component rendering `App`.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  </App />
</BrowserRouter>
```